# Trying to change the index column of a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Pandas Series, it looks like this when I output it to a CSV-

```
a_x,8
b_x,14
c_x,18
d_x,26
e_x,32
```

Here is the result I am trying to achieve-

```
a_bar,8
b_bar,14
c_bar,18
d_bar,26
e_bar,32
```

Seems like a simple operation but just can't get the result yet.
Thank you.

Comment: `df.index = df.index.str.replace('x', 'bar')`, probably. You might want to check out the [Working with Text Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) part of the docs.

Answer (score 4):

solution=

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace('x', 'bar')
```

solved by Mitch, thanks